# Difference between Sobolev norm and L2 norm for regularization?

Tags: regularization

I am interested to find a inverse solution of the problem defined below, which means I want to find $\tilde{y}$.

$M_{\delta}^{\alpha}[\tilde{y}]=\|A\tilde{y}-\tilde{b}\|_{L_2}^2 + \alpha\|\tilde{y}\|_{L_2}^2, \\
y_{\alpha}=argminM_{\delta}^{\alpha}[\tilde{y}],$

where $M_{\delta}^{\alpha}[\tilde{y}]$ is a smoothing functional, $\alpha$ is a regularization parameter and $y_{\alpha}$ is a regularized solution that provides a global minimum of the functional $M$.

My question is: Instead of ${L_2}$ norm in the second term ($\alpha\|\tilde{y}\|_{L_2}^2$) if I apply Sobolev norm as defined in the wikipedia link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space what kind of different solution we expect to obtain. I mean how different the estimate $y_{\alpha}$ would for the two different norms? What kind of functions I could expect to obtain under this two different norm regularization? I am looking for some intuitive answer to analyse what type of regularization would be appropriate for my research work. I am dealing with signal added with Gaussian noise. The convolution matrix $A$ is known and its column are narrow band complex sinusoid.  In addition I am expecting a sparse solution so I tried $L_1$ norm. Now, I am wondering how Sobolev norm would fit into this problem? What should I expect if I use Sobolev norm? Specifically, for Gaussian noise removal can we compare the performance of $L_1$ regularization and Sobolev norm?

Comment: Well, that's somehow standard in books on regularization of ill-posed problems (e.g. Engl, Hanke, Neubauer). Roughly, in general $L^2$ regularization gives $L^2$ solutions, $H^1$ regularization gives $H^2$ solutions.  Even smoother if $A^*$ is smoothing.

Comment: With $L^1$ regularization you get sparse solutions, with Sobolev regularization you get smooth solutions.  But you probably know this already… Seems like you try to discuss your problem and not to ask a question. Hence, voting to close as unclear, what you're asking.

Comment: @Dirk The question is more towards why? For what properties of norm, so that I can understand the difference geometrically.